# how can i check if almost all rows are identical and if so then verify that the final differing row varies by some constant k

Tags: python, pandas, comparison, filtering, rows

**using iris data set with dimension (150,4) I want to see if the rows are identical in columns 1 2 and 4 and if so then verify that the 3rd column has values differing by some constant k. This has to be done for every possible row combination.**

```
#### load data###
import pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame(iris.data,columns=iris.feature_names)
df.head()
```

this gives me an error "The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()." and also does not account for all the rows

**I chose k=4 here**

```
list=range(0,148)

for row in list:
    if df.iloc[row,:]==df.iloc[row+1,:]:
        df.iloc[row,2]-df.iloc[row+1,2]<=4
    else:
        print('nothing')
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message basically tells you how to fix this:

```
if df.iloc[row,:]==df.iloc[row+1,:]:
```

it needs to be:

```
if (df.iloc[row,:]==df.iloc[row+1,:]).all():
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to filter the columns you want to compare. In this case columns 0, 1 and 3 by doing the following comparison `df.iloc[row1,[0, 1, 3]] == df.iloc[row2, [0, 1, 3]]`. This returns an array of True or False values. But you need *all* columns to be the same. To acomplish that you need the `.all()` method. It returns true only if all values in the array are True. In summary:

```
if (df.iloc[row1,identical_columns] == df.iloc[row2, identical_columns]).all():
```

And since you need to iterate over every posible row combination a double for loop will do nicely.

```
for row1 in range(m-1):
    for row2 in range(row1+1, m):
        # Check for every row combinaton if the columns are equal
        if (df.iloc[row1,identical_columns] == df.iloc[row2, identical_columns]).all():
            pass
```

Altogether:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(data=np.random.randint(0, 100, (10, 4)))
m = df.shape[0]

identical_columns = [0, 1, 3]
k = 4

# Force rows values to pass
df.iloc[2, :] = [3, 4, 5, 1]
df.iloc[3, :] = [3, 4, 4, 1]

for row1 in range(m-1):
    for row2 in range(row1+1, m):
        # Check for every row combinaton if the columns are equal
        if (df.iloc[row1,identical_columns] == df.iloc[row2, identical_columns]).all():


            if df.iloc[row1,2] - df.iloc[row2,2] <= k:
                # TODO: Implement Your logic
                print ('We pass!')
        else:
            print(f"row {row1} and row {row2} don't pass")
```